# JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: HTTP status=400

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, http-status-code-400

I tried to connect to Snowflake DB by uisng snowflake jdbc 3.7.2 via providing a connection String.
The format of the string was:

```
jdbc:snowflake://xxxxx.snowflakecomputing.com/?&db=&warehouse=&role=&authenticator=
```

I tried with the following string as well:

```
jdbc:snowflake://xxxxx.snowflakecomputing.com/?db=&warehouse=&role=&authenticator=
```

But I'm not able to get any solution for the error. I'm getting the error:

```
SQL Exceptionnet.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: HTTP status=400.
```

Have anyone faced this issue before? How to solve this one?

Comment: Might help: "400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error with the proxy port. I was not using the port mentioned in the proxy settings. Hence, I was getting the error.

Thank you Rich for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including values for username/etc?

Here's an example of a JDBC url that should work, it also has tracing set, which should help for further debugging.

```
jdbc:snowflake://xxxxx.snowflakecomputing.com/?user=USERID-HERE&role=ROLE-HERE&warehouse=WAREHOUSE-HERE&db=DATABASE-HERE&schema=SCHEMA-HERE&tracing=ALL
```

The docs for configuring the connections can be found at this link:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html

Comment: I'm not passing any username values in the URL. I'm passing username and password in properties.

Comment: if you are using properties in your .getconnection - then you should not include those parameters (arguments) in the jdbc url, see the examples in this document:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#connection-parameters

Comment: I'm following them. Username and Password are not provided in the JDBC URL. I am using the second method provided there.